# Оптимизация if-else и switch

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

В книге пишется, что нужно избегать этих 2 циклов и использовать поисковые таблицы ,если проверок очень много.

`switch` больше подходит когда для отдельного ключа требуется отдельная операция. 
Так у меня вопрос -можно посмотреть на это?
Неужели там идет перебор через цикл `for` и идет сравнение... Если да,то чем это лучше.

Comment: А что за "поисковые таблицы"? можно ссылку где про них написано?

Comment: гугл молчит ,а прочитал ее в книге автор: Закас "оптимизация javascript". Кстати она доступна русском http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4198867

Comment: А, ну понятно все. Так в чем, собственно, вопрос. Не совсем понятно.

Comment: увидеть глазами эту самую поисковую таблицу и работу с ней

Comment: Под поисковой таблицей автор видимо понимает key-value хранилище.

Comment: @SoWa, так и есть.

Comment: спасибо.Сейчас попробую на практике

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из самых ярких примеров - реализация такой схемы в библиотеке `ExtJs`. Там есть метод `Ext.getCmp`, который возвращает объект по его `id`. А объектов там может быть больше тысячи. Это реализовано довольно просто:

При создании нового какого-либо объекта, он регистрируется в одной глобальной статической переменной таким образом:

```
add(key, value) {
    this.map[key] = value;
}
```

Тут  приходит в качестве ключа - id объекта, а в качестве value - ссылка на него. И теперь, чтобы быстро и без потери производительности взять нужный объект по его id, достаточно вызвать примерно такой метод:

```
get:(key) {
    return this.map[key];
}
```

PS: Я тут очень сильно упростил оригинальный код ExtJs для более лучшего понимания.

**UPD1**:
 Забыл написать что `map` может быть как массивом, так и объектом:

```
map={};
//или
map=[];
```

Comment: map может быть массивом, но должен быть объектом* :)

Comment: Да, верно. Просто хотел показать что не только так можно :)

Answer (score 1):

Очень много - это сколько? Если у тебя switch на 10 условий, в каждом из которых по одной-две строки, то switch пиши, не критично. А если у тебя те же 10 операций, но в каждой строк на 50-100 метод (например контроллер пишешь), то конечно лучше "поисковые таблицы".

А if-else если дальше закручивать - if-else if-else if-else if-else if-... это лапша получится. Используй не более одного раза